# Updating multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

i tried to search and search but i couldn't find a matching answer. 
I need to update 300 rows in the database and the query seems to become longer and longer. I know i can make a temp table somehow, but i'm stuck.
Below an example of the table

```
ProductID | (Old)ArticleNumber | (New)ArticleNumber
268687    |      EXRO300       |       5709070
268702    |      EXS50030      |       1595831
268728    |      EX62111       |       1562993
268730    |      EXRT25        |       1009451
268733    |      EX240220V     |       7800100
268737    |      EX600         |       1875928
..........|....................|.................
```

And then like 300 rows. 
So, old articlenumber needs to be replaced by the new...

Comment: How do we know what (New)ArticleNumbers to update to?

Comment: The new ones needs to overwrite the old ones. So EXRO300 needs to become 5709070. The only issue is that i have 300+ of them :/

Comment: But how do you know the new values???

Comment: @Bas - Put old and new ArticleNumber columns into another table  and then use `UPDATE JOIN`

Comment: You Can Make a Dynamically Query for Update

Answer (score 1):

If you have `New Article Nr` in another table in db, join it via `ProductID` and set them like:

```
UPDATE oldProductTbl
SET oldProductTbl.ArticleNumber = newProductTbl.ArticleNumber
FROM Products1 oldProductTbl
    JOIN Product2 newProductTbl 
    ON oldProductTbl.ProductId = newProductTbl.ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to update data in temporary table

```
 UPDATE
     Table_A
  SET
    Table_A.(old)ArticleNumber = Table_A.(New)ArticleNumber,
 FROM
     Some_Table AS Table_A
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new temp table with the new article numbers and ProductID's.

```
CREATE TABLE #NewArticle(
ProductID int,
ArticleNumber char(30) )
```

Then i used an insert into table to fill it.

```
insert into #NewArticle(ProductID,NewArticle)
VALUES ('268687'),('5709070'),
('269364','HA61451CTH'),
('269393','5665237'),
........
```

And then this to update it all.

```
update tblProduct
set NewArticle = #NewArticle.NewArticle
from tblProduct
inner join #NewArticle on tblproduct.ProductID = #NewArticle.ProductID
```

Nice! Thanks a lot!